# Mandatory test success with Ionic/Cordova build

Tags: cordova, unit-testing, ionic-framework, build, automated-tests

This may be a dumb question but I didn't find out something relevant to answer it on the web so far...

I'm working on an Ionic/Cordova mobile application and I'd like to set up some automated tests.
I'm from the Java world and I'd like to set it up like I would set up tests with Maven: when I try to build the app (ionic/cordova build android/ios), this command launches automatically the tests and if a test does not pass successfully, the build must stop and not produce the package.

I found a lot of stuff on the web but it seems that the tests are either non-blocking, either run manually, which does not suit me.

To publish on the Apple AppStore, the release is always manual because we manually check some fine tuning in XCode, so the release build tends to always be manual and I want to prevent that one could build without running tests.

Is there any good way to do that?

PS: I tried to use the Cordova before_build hook, but it seems to be run in Microsoft JScript, which has no console and if an uncatched error happens, it does not stop the build... so it does not feel like the good option.

Thank you by advance!

SJ

Comment: Maybe the best way to do this is to change the build tool and not to use the Cordova/Ionic CLI? 
I think this is possible to start cordova build from grunt/gulp, is it possible too for the ionic command?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use the Cordova before_build hook, but it seems to be run in Microsoft JScript, which has no console and if an uncatched error happens, it does not stop the build`

Cordova hook scripts run using NodeJS and exiting with a non-zero error code will stop the build, so you can do something like this:

project_dir/hooks/before_build/run_maven_tests.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cliCommand = "mvn surefire:test";

exec(cliCommand, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if(err){
        console.error("Tests failed - aborting build");
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log("Tests passed"):
};
```